# Should [whs] be a synonym for [windows-home-server]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonym-request

Seems like [whs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/whs) and [windows-home-server](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-home-server) tags are the same topic.

I do not have the privilege to formally suggest this synonym myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done. And I merged [windows-home-server-v1](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-home-server-v1) as well.